# Card Number regular expression help

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I have used the following command+REGEX to list all the files contain card numbers in a set of files.

`grep -r -l -e '[3-6]\d{3}([\ \-]?)\d{4}([\ \-]?)\d{4}([\ \-]?)\d{3,4}' *`

I have tested this REGEX at a different application and it was successful.

Comment: You should add some input data, expected output, and actual output. Also, what site are you talking about? Regex are pretty notorious for having different escape sequences and syntaxes across implementations.

Comment: what is your question ? What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: What card numbers are you talking about?

Comment: pardon me. I have edited the question. This is to identify credit/debit card numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain grep uses basic regular expressions. Your regex uses `-d` and `?` and `{m,n}` that aren't recognized.

You want `grep -E`, but that may not recognize `\d`. If not change it to `[0-9]`

```
grep -Erle '[3-6][0-9]{3}([ -]?)[0-9]{4}([ -]?)[0-9]{4}([ -]?)[0-9]{3,4}' *
```

Or use `grep -P` to use perl-compatible regexes

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html

Comment: GNU grep in Debian Wheezy apparently does not understand `\d` in `-E` mode. `echo '1234' | grep -E '^\d{4}$'` outputs nothing vs `echo '1234' | grep -E '^[0-9]{4}$'` which outputs `1234`. That's version 2.12. Of course, there's `[[:digit:]]` for `echo '1234' | grep -E '^[[:digit:]]{4}$'` which does work.